# Introduction to the Adler-van Moerbeke theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, integrable-systems

Is there a good introduction to the Adler-van Moerbeke theory of solving completely integrable systems by linearizing the flow on the Jacobian of an algebraic curve, for someone with a background in differential geometry, not so familiar with the theory of algebraic curves?

Comment: Does *[Integrable Systems in the Realm of Algebraic Geometry](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540423379)* by Pol Vanhaecke cover what you're looking for? Particularly chapter VI, section 5, Proposition 5.1.